# How to edit standard field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How do I edit a standard field in salesforce? I am using Developer edition.

Answer (score 5):

After login,

1. Click your user-name in the top right
2. Click setup
3. Under App Setup on the left side-bar, expand customize
   (Note: for custom objects, expand create instead and click Objects to view a list)
4. Expand the standard object you would like to edit the standard field for
5. Click Fields
6. If the field can be edited, in the standard field list, there will be an edit button on the left
7. Click edit

Answer (score 1):

generally you can't do much editing on salesforce fields except their help text.

Comment: Labels as well, since customizing the label keeps the "big wigs" happy :)